Is anyone running public electrum server with websockets?
It seems websockets should be supported by major implementations (checked fulcrum and electrum). https://1209k.com/bitcoin-eye/ele.php?chain=btc has not a single websocket enabled electrum server listed.
Is there a reason no one is running it?
